# Oracle java 7 Installation in Ubuntu E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: java, ubuntu, error-code

I can't install oracle java 7 following the steps provided in this link:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  visualvm ttf-baekmuk ttf-unfonts ttf-unfonts-core ttf-kochi-gothic
  ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  oracle-java7-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/18,6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 193 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java7-installer.
(Reading database ... 273801 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking oracle-java7-installer (from .../oracle-java7-installer_7u51-0~webupd8~4_all.deb) ...
oracle-license-v1-1 license has already been accepted
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u51-0~webupd8~4) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2014-03-20 12:12:52--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 131.178.7.201
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|131.178.7.201|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2014-03-20 12:12:52--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.204.22.140
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.204.22.140|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1395339292_7fc586697ce74b02fa16cb3ec88d3a9d [following]
--2014-03-20 12:12:52--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1395339292_7fc586697ce74b02fa16cb3ec88d3a9d
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|131.178.7.201|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable

    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.

Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also tried doing what says in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer*
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*
sudo apt-get update
```

Then:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

And still no luck :(
Could anyone help me?
I am quite lost at why It isn't working.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Found a solution in the following link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/414885/oracle-jdk-7-is-not-installed-error

SOLUTION:

```
sudo dpkg -P oracle-java7-installer
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Answer (score 16):

Please follow below steps to install oracle java:

**Download** the *latest* Java SE SDK version.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

**Untar the Archive**:

```
tar -xzvf jdk-8-linux-x64.tar.gz
mv jdk1.8.0 /opt 
cd /opt/jdk1.8.0
```

This step registers the downloaded version of Java as an alternative, and switches it to be used as the default:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac 1
update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so mozilla-javaplugin.so /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so 1
update-alternatives --set java /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
update-alternatives --set javac /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac
update-alternatives --set mozilla-javaplugin.so /opt/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
```

**Test**

To check the version of Java you are now running

```
java -version
```

**Output**

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

To check the browser plugin browse to http://www.java.com/ and click “Do I have Java?”

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/437776/ubuntu-13-04-unable-to-install-jdk7

Comment: update-alternatives: error: error creating symbolic link '/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so.dpkg-tmp': No such file or directory

Comment: @JuniorM may be the java directory got changed with your firefox version. Possible fix would be replacing `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so.dpkg-tmp` to `/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins/libjavaplugin.so.dpkg-tmp` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/chrishantha/install-java/issues/1#issue-175641209).

Comment: I was struggling after oracle stopped offering jdk7u80. Thank YOU :)

Answer (score 2):

1. install synaptic if do not install before than.
2. open synaptic package manager.
3. search jdk.
4. mark for removal all jdk installed package .
5. apply to remove.
6. mark for installation  `openjdk-8-jdk`.
7. apply.
8. N-joy.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`sudo dpkg -P oracle-java7-installer`

`sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 1):

i think that your download is corrupted
you have to remove the corrupted package first by code :

```
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer
```

clean your apt :

```
sudo apt clean
```

remove and reimport the ropsitory:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

install your package again :

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

enjoy it bro ! if the problem hasn't solved try using VPN . Maybe there is a filtering between you and the oracle website

Answer (score 0):

The reason is :  [WHY ORACLE JAVA 7 AND 6 INSTALLERS NO LONGER WORK](http://www.webupd8.org/2017/06/why-oracle-java-7-and-6-installers-no.html)

If you have an Oracle Support account and you really need Oracle JDK 6 or 7, you can get the installers from the WebUpd8 PPA to work by downloading the binaries and placing them in the following folder:

- /var/cache/oracle-jdk6-installer/ for JDK 6 (you'll need version 6u45)
- /var/cache/oracle-jdk7-installer/ for JDK 7 (you'll need version 7u80 for 32bit and 64bit or 7u60 for arm)

... and then install the oracle-java6-installer or oracle-java7-installer package.

Answer (score -1):

Tried with the solution but still not working. Even when I tried to download the jdk tar from the Oracle site it still failed at around 30-50MB.
Anyway I found an article which talks about it and finally got it fixed!

[Oracle Adds License to oracle-java7-installer and Now It Fails](http://tiemensfamily.com/TimOnCS/2014/03/15/oracle-adds-license-to-java7-installer-fails/) (published on March 2014)

Basically the steps are similar except the last one:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: Those instructions don't work.Use these:

`sudo dpkg -P oracle-java7-installer`
`sudo apt-get -f install`
`sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer`

Comment: Hey, thanks for comment. One need to purge the package if the previous installation failed. I have run both these command. sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer is now no longer working. I have tried at least more than 3 times. use oracle-java8-installer instead. you can refer to the url above for explanation.