# sha256sum mismatch error installing Oracle Java 7 on crunchbang wheezy

Tags: java, linux, debian, mismatch

I have spend the better part of today trying to install java 7 on my crunchbang distro. I originally had OpenJDK installed but ran into issues with a mumble server install. That is sorted now (somehow), but now I don't have java 7 or OpenJDK. My java version is:

```
matt@crunchbang:~$ java -version
java version "1.5.0"
gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.7.2

Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

When attempting to install java 7
(`sudo apt-get install Oracle-java7-installer`)I end up with an error looking like this:

```
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u7-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Things I have tried:

- removing java & java installers
- Purging java and java isntallers
- Using a script found on stack overflow to show me what installed programs are relying on java, then uninstalling those. (this displayed libreoffice packages and several java installers)
- Downloading jre 7 from website, decompressing it, copying to 'usr/lib/jvm/' and symlinking it to the java 5 folder
- *This* users [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541853/oracle-java-7-installation-in-ubuntu-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-er?rq=1)

---

Full java install log:

```
matt@crunchbang:~$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-opensymbol fonts-sil-gentium fonts-sil-gentium-basic gcj-4.7-base gcj-4.7-jre gcj-4.7-jre-headless gcj-4.7-jre-lib gcj-jre
  gcj-jre-headless libapache-pom-java libcmis-0.2-0 libcommons-beanutils-java libcommons-collections3-java libcommons-compress-java
  libcommons-digester-java libcommons-logging-java libcommons-parent-java libdb-java libdb-je-java libdb5.1-java libdb5.1-java-jni
  libexttextcat-data libexttextcat0 libgcj-common libgcj13 libgcj13-awt libgraphite2-2.0.0 libhsqldb-java libhyphen0 libicu4j-java
  libjaxp1.3-java libjline-java libjtidy-java liblucene2-java libmythes-1.2-0 libneon27-gnutls libnss3-1d libregexp-java libservlet2.5-java
  libvisio-0.0-0 libxalan2-java libxerces2-java libxml-commons-external-java libxml-commons-resolver1.1-java libxz-java
  ttf-sil-gentium-basic uno-libs3 ure xfonts-mathml
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  binfmt-support visualvm ttf-baekmuk ttf-unfonts ttf-unfonts-core ttf-kochi-gothic ttf-sazanami-gothic ttf-kochi-mincho
  ttf-sazanami-mincho ttf-arphic-uming
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  oracle-java7-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/16.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 88.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java7-installer.
(Reading database ... 94766 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking oracle-java7-installer (from .../oracle-java7-installer_7u7-0~crunchbang~4_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u7-0~crunchbang~4) ...
Removing outdated cached downloads...
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2014-05-23 15:35:08--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u7-b10/jdk-7u7-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.73.181.33, 23.73.181.26
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.73.181.33|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u7-b10/jdk-7u7-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2014-05-23 15:35:08--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u7-b10/jdk-7u7-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.78.166.140
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.78.166.140|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html [following]
--2014-05-23 15:35:09--  http://download.oracle.com/errors/download-fail-1505220.html
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.73.181.33|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5307 (5.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: `jdk-7u7-linux-x64.tar.gz'

     0K                                                      100% 3.48M=0.001s

2014-05-23 15:35:09 (3.48 MB/s) - `jdk-7u7-linux-x64.tar.gz' saved [5307/5307]

Download done.
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u7-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Did [this suggestion](http://askubuntu.com/questions/434675/java-7-installation-error) fail too?

Comment: @thatotherguy it failed with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running crunchbang wheezy on my chromebook and had the exact same problem.

This fixxed it for me:

> I had a similar problem and what i found that worked for me was going
>   into /var/lib/dpkg/info and deleting everything that had that name and
>   you may also have to go into /var/cache/apt/archives and do the same
>   thing. I'm fairly new to linux so if this breaks anything i am sorry.
>   i haven't run into any problems yet that this has caused.

**WARNING:**

> You are deleting the pre and post install scripts. This can very easily
>   mean that the package will not be installed properly, and it won't be
>   removed properly if you choose to uninstall it. It is THE WRONG THING
>   to do.

However, I couldn't find any other solutions. Granted, I was in a bit of a rush to fix this problem, so I didn't really spend too much time looking for an alternative solution.

*(Solution and quotes taken from: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-a-171107/)*