# Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.Subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, proxy

I have Java 8 installed and set as default. This is on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

```
bernard@bernard-Lenovo-G580:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

Whenever I try to install maven I get this error.

```
bernard@bernard-Lenovo-G580:~$ sudo apt-get install maven
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done
maven is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-36 linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
28 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u20+8u6arm-1~webupd8~0) ...
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2014-09-30 14:54:20--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u20-b26/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 62.8.89.22, 62.8.89.25
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|62.8.89.22|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u20-b26/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2014-09-30 14:54:20--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u20-b26/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz
Connecting to 172.16.0.83:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2014-09-30 14:56:28--  (try: 2)  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u20-b26/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz
Connecting to 172.16.0.83:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2014-09-30 14:58:38--  (try: 3)  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u20-b26/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz
Connecting to 172.16.0.83:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2014-09-30 15:00:48--  (try: 4)  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u20-b26/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz
Connecting to 172.16.0.83:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2014-09-30 15:02:59--  (try: 5)  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u20-b26/jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz
Connecting to 172.16.0.83:8080... failed: Connection timed out.
Giving up.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of junit4:
 junit4 depends on default-jre-headless | java5-runtime-headless; however:
  Package default-jre-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides default-jre-headless is not configured yet.
  Package java5-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides java5-runtime-headless is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package junit4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libbatik-java:
 libbatik-java depends on default-jre-headless | java2-runtime-headless; however:
  Package default-jre-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides default-jre-headless is not configured yet.
  Package java2-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides java2-runtime-headless is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libbatik-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfop-java:
 libfop-java depends on libbatik-java (>= 1.7); however:
  Package libbatik-java is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libfop-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdoxia-java:
 libdoxia-java depends on libfop-java; however:
  Package libfop-java is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libdoxia-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bsh:
 bsh depends on default-jre-headless | java1-runtime-headless | java2-runtime-headless; however:
  Package default-jre-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides default-jre-headless is not configured yet.
  Package java1-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package java2-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides java2-runtime-headless is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package bsh (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libplexus-bsh-factory-java:No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

 libplexus-bsh-factory-java depends on bsh; however:
  Package bsh is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libplexus-bsh-factory-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

dpkg: error processing package libmaven2-core-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmaven-scm-java:
 libmaven-scm-java depends on libmaven2-core-java; however:
  Package libmaven2-core-java is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libmaven-scm-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libwagon-java:
 libwagon-java depends on junit4; however:
  Package junit4 is not configured yet.
 libwagon-java depends on libmaven-scm-java; however:
  Package libmaven-scm-java is not configured yet.

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of maven:
 maven depends on default-jre (>= 1:1.5) | default-jre-headless (>= 1:1.5) | java5-runtime | java5-runtime-headless; however:
  Package default-jre is not installed.
  Package default-jre-headless is not installed.
  Package java5-runtime is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides java5-runtime is not configured yet.
  Package java5-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides java5-runtime-headless is not configured yet.
 maven depends on libaether-java; however:
  Package libaether-java is not configured yet.
 maven depends on libplexus-containers1.5-java; however:
  Package libplexus-containers1.5-java is not configured yet.
 maven depends on libsisu-ioc-java; however:
  Package libsisu-ioc-java is not configured yet.
 maven depends on libwagon2-java (>= 2.2-2); however:
  Package libwagon2-java is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package maven (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhino:
 rhino depends on default-jre-headless (>= 1.5) | java5-runtime-headless; however:
  Package default-jre-headless is not installed.
  Package java5-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides java5-runtime-headless is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhino (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 junit4
 libbatik-java
 libfop-java
 libdoxia-java
 bsh
 libplexus-bsh-factory-java
 libmaven2-core-java
 libmaven-scm-java
 libwagon-java
 libplexus-containers1.5-java
 libgeronimo-interceptor-3.0-spec-java
 libcdi-api-java
 libsisu-ioc-java
 libaether-java
 libwagon2-java
 maven
 rhino
 android-studio
 ant
 ant-optional
 aspectj
 fop
 libgeronimo-jpa-2.0-spec-java
 libosgi-compendium-java
 libgeronimo-osgi-support-java
 oracle-java8-set-default
 testng
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

<strong>Java installation:</strong>
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /opt/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java        1    auto mode 
* 1            /opt/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java                  1         manual mode
  2            /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/jre/bin/java   1         manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:

<strong>Java version query:</strong>
bernard@bernard-Lenovo-G580:~$
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

<strong>Proxy configuration:</strong>
bernard@bernard-Lenovo-G580:~$ env | grep proxy
bernard@bernard-Lenovo-G580:~$
```

I have even tried to set the update alternatives instructions here [Oracle java 7 Installation in Ubuntu E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541853/oracle-java-7-installation-in-ubuntu-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-er) but apt is still trying to download java 8(Why? I have no clue.)using a proxy.

**I have also tried apt troubleshooting instructions here:**
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure but I still keep getting the proxy connection timeout error and Subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Comment: Just download Maven from http://maven.apache.org/download.html and that's it.

Comment: After a month of errors apt is finally playing nicely. I uninstalled Java, then rm -rf all packages in /var with *orac*. purge any packages with *orac* and do a clean install. Hopefully it helps someone else.

Comment: change the proxy in wgetrc config file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do what helped me in similiar case:

- go to Oracle JDK 8 download page and download exactly same version of jdk that oracle-java8-installer tried to download. In your case it's `jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz`. So you should download from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html
- copy jdk-8u20-linux-x64.tar.gz to folder:  `/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/`
- try install oracle-java8-installer:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
  ```

This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

See [dpkg-error-processing-package-oracle-java8-installer-configure/48332346#48332346](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48332346/2450431) for instructions.

PPA `ppa:webupd8team/java` is using archived Oracle packages which have been moved and the whole install fails as it can not download needed files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java8-installer-local.postinst -f
sudo dpkg --configure oracle-java8-installer-local
```