# dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):

Tags: java, scala, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html) on Ubuntu 16.04. I have mistakenly stopped the process when running the following command,

```
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

Now when I try to install again, I am getting the below error,

```
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2017-04-24 17:34:33--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 104.80.89.58, 104.80.89.16
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.80.89.58|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2017-04-24 17:34:35--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.200.209.153, 2600:1409:a:183::2d3e, 2600:1409:a:193::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.200.209.153|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1493035597_d0396e6a99df9ccfeb3f6d895673df09 [following]
--2017-04-24 17:34:37--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1493035597_d0396e6a99df9ccfeb3f6d895673df09
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.80.89.58|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable

    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.

Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sbt:
 sbt depends on openjdk-8-jdk; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jdk is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides openjdk-8-jdk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sbt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 sbt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I solve this?

**Update 1:**

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41386629/1381266). But still it didn't help me to solve this issue and getting the same error below?

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u131-1~webupd8~2) ...
Installing from local file /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz
Removing outdated cached downloads...
install: cannot stat 'javaws-wrapper.sh': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sbt:
 sbt depends on openjdk-8-jdk; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jdk is not installed.
  Package oracle-java8-installer which provides openjdk-8-jdk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sbt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 sbt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.Subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121499/oracle-jdk-8-is-not-installed-subprocess-installed-post-installation-script-retu)

Comment: @EvgenyVeretennikov That doesn't solve my issue. Refer my update in question.

Comment: Hi @karan, could you consider my solution below? If it's useful, please mark it as the answer in order to help other searches it easier.

Comment: This [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/976355/683977) solved the issue for me

Answer (score 78):

it's so long time since you asked. Because of no answer here, I show you my solution that works well for me.

The root cause of your problem may be from previous java install (it's not from any repositories, but from manually download package).
Thus, you must manually remove post-install scripts, use below commands:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java8-installer.postinst -f
sudo dpkg --configure oracle-java8-installer
```

Hope them help you.

Comment: Worked for me when fixing my java-11 issue with the same error message :)

Comment: I am having a weird issue where`java -version` looks okay but getting errors:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185084/ubuntu-oracle-jdk-issues-but-version-looks-okay

Answer (score 25):

For Ubuntu 19.04 and Oracle JDK 11:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java11-installer-local.postinst -f
sudo dpkg --configure oracle-java11-installer-local
```

Answer (score 8):

---

**!! NOTE !!**
**This solution may not work if Oracle stops serving files from their FTP service.
They do that for older Java releases.**

---

When using `ppa:webupd8team/java` there can be deprecated/archived Oracle links hardcoded in PPA.
Oracle is moving their older versions to archive and PPA has internal links to "active" (at the time of PPA creation) Oracle download versions.

The maintainer of `ppa:webupd8team/java` is only one man - Andrew (see [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686&p=13699352#post13699352))

**Problem**

```
download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Solution**

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u151|JAVA_VERSION=8u162|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u162-b12/0da788060d494f5095bf8624735fa2f1/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="c78200ce409367b296ec39be4427f020e2c585470c4eed01021feada576f027f"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="68ec82d47fd9c2b8eb84225b6db398a72008285fafc98631b1ff8d2229680257"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_151|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_162|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

> Java versions change "often" so update `8u151` and `8u162` to reflect your environment. (this versions worked on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS - 2018-01-18)

**Try again**

```
apt install oracle-java8-installer
apt install oracle-java8-set-default
```

**Read more about the problem**

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686&p=13699352#post13699352
- https://disqus.com/home/discussion/webupd8/install_oracle_java_8_in_ubuntu_via_ppa_jdk8_web_upd8_ubuntu_linux_blog/newest/
- http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for this answer, as it helped me out of a head-scratcher. This is the sort of information that is so hard to find, and I appreciate you sharing. Cheers!

Comment: I posted it in detail because it kept me awake last night too long and I wanted to save somebody the trouble I had last night. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Still not workin for me: / I get the following error `sed: can't read oracle-java8-installer.*: No such file or directory` Any idea why? I tried all the solutions below. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS bionic

Comment: @Newskooler you should use newer Java LTS version. Or better jet use OpenJDK (e.g. Zulu OpenJDK Builds). Oracle Java requires registration and download behind a login as of April 16, 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with 16.0.4:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u181|JAVA_VERSION=8u191|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u181-b13/96a7b8442fe848ef90c96a2fad6ed6d1/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="1845567095bfbfebd42ed0d09397939796d05456290fb20a83c476ba09f991d3"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="53c29507e2405a7ffdbba627e6d64856089b094867479edc5ede4105c1da0d65"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_181|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_191|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked in Ubuntu 18.10

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u191|JAVA_VERSION=8u201|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u191-b12/2787e4a523244c269598db4e85c51e0c/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u201-b09/42970487e3af4f5aa5bca3f542482c60/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="53c29507e2405a7ffdbba627e6d64856089b094867479edc5ede4105c1da0d65"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="cb700cc0ac3ddc728a567c350881ce7e25118eaf7ca97ca9705d4580c506e370"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_191|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_201|' oracle-java8-installer.*
```